# How can I close video box layer in revolution slider?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a video layer that appears when I click a button. I want the video layer to disappear when I click outside the video layer. Is that possible? There is no help or information on their website.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure it is possible using Javascript. Just pit an eventlistener on the document level and check whether the target is the video or not. If not, close the video.